# Добавить header в сообщение kafka producer на python

Tags: python, post, header, apache-kafka

Имеется kafka producer написанный на python и работающий по принципу прокси. То есть на продюсер приходит сообщение извне, обрабатывается и перенаправляется в кафку. Но столкнулся с ошибкой: **in send assert type(headers) == list AssertionError**

Код моего продюсера

```
import kafka
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import re 
import json
class HandleRequests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    producer = kafka.producer.KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['перечень ip'])
                                               
                                             
    
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        

    def do_POST(self):
        '''Reads post request body'''
        
        self._set_headers()
        content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        
        self._send_kafka(post_body)
        
        
    def do_PUT(self):
        self.do_POST()

    def _send_kafka(self, body):
        self.producer.send("topic", bytes(body))


host = ''
port = 9000
HTTPServer((host, port), HandleRequests).serve_forever()
```

С тем, чтобы отправлять просто сообщения он справляется. Но мне потребовалось ещё дополнительно отправлять заголовки вместе с сообщением.

Что я пытался сделать

Добавлять:
`KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))`

Преобразовывать в самом send:

```
def _send_kafka(self, body):
    head={"a": "asdasdads", "b": "qweqwe" и тд}
    self.producer.send("topic", bytes(body), headers=json.dumps(head).encode('utf-8'))
```

Также пытался саму переменную head преобразовывать в разные форматы.

Но всегда ошибка:
in send assert type(headers) == list
AssertionError

Нагуглить готовый пример не получилось, поэтому прошу подсказать как с этим работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях помогает только одно - изучать [исходный код](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/producer/kafka.py#L562-L563):

> **headers** (optional): a list of header key value pairs. List items
> are tuples of str key and bytes value.

Пример использования из их же [unit тестов](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/test/test_producer.py#L95-L105):

```
    # record headers are supported in 0.11.0
    if env_kafka_version() < (0, 11, 0):
        headers = None
    else:
        headers = [("Header Key", b"Header Value")]

    topic = random_string(5)
    future = producer.send(
        topic,
        value=b"Simple value", key=b"Simple key", headers=headers, timestamp_ms=9999999,
        partition=0)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пример с unit тестом показал, как правильно кортеж передать. Теперь работает